# Python Requests Get State

Tags: python, authentication, python-requests, auth0

Trying to use the requests package to login to https://apps.kbnfinans.kommunalbanken.no/access/

When accessing this page I need to get the "state" and "auth0Client".
Look at the picture below. When opening the webpage above - javascript opens different pages. How do I grab this GET request with Python Requests?

This authentication is an auth0 auth method.

[image: Dev Tools]

Comment: you can access  response headers or cookies no problem ..

Comment: @JoranBeasley The page does a new request with "request headers". This values in this request is what I am trying to grab.

Comment: you havent posted any code .... please read about minimum viable code example :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use something like [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/) with headless chrome browser to emulate users behaviour and render javascript if site doesn't provide an API to do that.

In case parameters are known just append it as [headers](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#custom-headers) or as a [query string](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls)

Comment: Does Selenium (Headless Chrome) work when the computer is locked (Win + L)? I believe I tried Selenium (not headless), and that it didnt work when the computer was locked.